# Software for merging git pull requests on a schedule?

Tags: automation, scheduling, github

I'm looking for some sort of rules-based or scheduling software that integrates with GitHub.

#### Features would be:

1. integrated with GitHub
2. possible to specify a time limit on Pull Requests (example 24 hours) before they are auto-merged if the defualt CI built into GitHub gives a green light.
3. reviewers are notified periodically that the PR will be merged and x minutes remain for them to provide feedback or comments

#### Previous Research:

I've spoken to the support team for ZenHub and although they didn't have anything like this right now, they noted it for consideration on their roadmap. Still, I'm wondering if there are already integrations or software for GitHub that do this?

#### Motivation

It would be great (just my 2 cts) for a PR that passes its CircleCI builds within GitHub ... to be auto-merged if reviewers don't respond with x hours. The notifications to the reviewers will place a greater burden of responsibility with them to either provide feedback or merge in a timely fashion ... or be held accountable for any undesired consequences.